# white space standard unit

Tags: units, white-space

Now, everytime I want to use hspace/vspace/... I always have to type "mm" behind my number and I often forget it. Is it possible to make sure that latex "knows" my units are in mm?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Why not simply defining an own version that doesn't interfere with TeX's units?

Comment: Can you give some example when you use `\hspace` and `\vspace`? Maybe there is a way to automatically generate your desired format without putting in manual spaces.

Comment: it's just in beamer when making my slides, to shift the text sometimes

Answer (score 3):

How about defining the following macros in the preamble

```
\newcommand\myhsp[1]{\hspace{#1mm}}
\newcommand\myvsp[1]{\vspace{#1mm}}
```

and writing `\myhsp{7}`, `\myvsp{12}`, etc in the body of the document?

This is safer than redefining the way `\hspace` and `\vspace` operate. These two macros are used in lots of LaTeX kernel commands, and modifying them has the potential to precipitate mysterious crashes. Don't even think about going there.

Answer (score 1):

Using @TeXnician's suggestion, the following could be an easy implementation:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\hspacemm}{\@ifstar{\hspacemm@@}{\hspacemm@}}
\newcommand*{\hspacemm@@}[1]{\hspace*{ #1 mm}}
\newcommand*{\hspacemm@}[1]{\hspace{ #1 mm}}
\newcommand*{\vspacemm}{\@ifstar{\vspacemm@@}{\vspacemm@}}
\newcommand*{\vspacemm@@}[1]{\vspace*{ #1 mm}}
\newcommand*{\vspacemm@}[1]{\vspace{ #1 mm}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent
\hspacemm*{10}This \hspacemm{20}is spaced\\
This not
\end{document}
```